# Combine multiple JS files into two files

Tags: laravel, gulp, browserify, laravel-elixir

I have 3 main JS files:

1. `base.js`
2. `notLoggedIn.js`
3. `loggedIn.js`

`base.js` contains all of the basic needs for my application and the other two files are self-explanatory.

What I need to do is this:

1. Combine `base.js` and `notLoggedIn.js` into `file1.js`.
2. Combine `base.js`, `notLoggedIn.js`, and `loggedIn.js` into `file2.js`.

And I need it in this order.

Here is what my `gulpfile.js` currently looks like:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .browserify('base.js');
});
```

How do I modify the file to meet my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all three scripts you mention are located in the `resources/assets/js` directory, you can do the following:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts(['base.js', 'notLoggedIn.js'], 'public/js/file1.js')
       .scripts(['base.js', 'notLoggedIn.js', 'loggedIn.js'], 'public/js/file2.js');
});
```